# How to allow the same navigation bar dropdown function to work in toggle collapse for React

Tags: reactjs, list, dropdown, toggle

My navigation bar is functioning as intended in my React application, however when the web app is resized to a smaller screen size, the toggle collapse bar is used. However, the dropdown item in the toggle collapse is not functioning the same as the navigation bar. When clicking on the toggle icon to access the collapsed navigation bar, the dropdown item automatically loads the dropdown items without needing to click on it to access the dropdown items.

Current Function: The default navigation bar is working as intended and the dropdown item "About Us" displays the dropdown items when it is hovered over, however when the screen is adjusted to a small size, the default navigation bar is transformed into a collapsed toggled navigation bar which automatically displays the dropdown items "About", "News" and "Career" from item "About Us" when the collapsed navigation bar is accessed, which is not useful for my case because I want to choose if I want to view the dropdown items or not on clicking the item "About Us.

Solution Needed: I need the collapsed toggled navigation bar to let me choose to click on the navigation bar item "About Us" and then it should dropdown the 3 items "About", "News" and "Career".

The Header Navigation Bar Code:

```
<div className='container-fluid navigation_bar'>
        <nav
          className='navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light'
          style={{ background: 'rgb(246, 246, 246)' }}
        >
          <a className='navbar-brand' href='./'>
            <img
              src={logo1}
              alt='navbar-brand'
              style={{
                paddingLeft: '25px',
                paddingRight: '48px',
                width: '284px',
                height: '53px'
              }}
            />
          </a>
          <button
            className='navbar-toggler'
            aria-controls='navbarNavAltMarkup'
            aria-expanded='false'
            aria-label='Toggle navigation'
            data-bs-target='#navbarNavAltMarkup'
            data-bs-toggle='collapse'
            type='button'
          >
            <span className='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
          </button>
          <div className='navbar-collapse collapse' id='navbarNavAltMarkup'>
            <div className='navbar-nav'>
              <a
                className='nav-button-dropdown nav-item nav-link active px-lg-3 px-sm-1 px-1'
                href='./'
              >
                Home <span className='sr-only'>(current)</span>
              </a>
              <a
                className='nav-button-dropdown nav-item nav-link px-lg-3 px-sm-3 px-1'
                href='./zense'
              >
                Zense Solution
              </a>
              <a
                className='nav-button-dropdown nav-item nav-link px-lg-3 px-sm-3 px-1'
                href='./enablingtechnologies'
              >
                Enabling Technologies
              </a>
              <li className='nav-item dropdown active'>
                <span
                  data-bs-target='#navbarNavAltMarkup'
                  aria-expanded='false'
                  className='nav-item nav-link dropdown-toggle px-lg-3 px-sm-3 px-1'
                >
                  About Us
                </span>
                <ul className='dropdown-menu' id='navbarNavAltMarkup'>
                  <li>
                    <a
                      className='nav-button-dropdown dropdown-item'
                      href='./about'
                    >
                      About
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a
                      className='nav-button-dropdown dropdown-item'
                      href='./news'
                    >
                      News
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a
                      className='nav-button-dropdown dropdown-item'
                      href='./career'
                    >
                      Career
                    </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <a
                className='nav-button-dropdown nav-item nav-link px-lg-3 px-sm-3 px-1'
                href='./contact'
              >
                Contact Us
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
```

I have attempted to change classNames, properties and expected the item "About Us" to not automatically display the dropdown items "About", "News" and "Career" when accessing the collapsed toggle navigation bar in the small sized screen adjusted by developer tools, but it was unsuccessful as the function had not changed.

Comment: I have used scss by setting display: none for the <ul> list and then everytime I hover over "About Us" item, the display: block. This is working now, but in developer tools the :hover function doesn't work. It forces me to click on items.

Comment: I have resolved my issue for computer browser displays, however on mobile, the hover effect won't be useful. I need to set the "About Us" item for a onClick() to then display the <ul> list to be display: block from diplay: none.